# Which executor is used when composing Java CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a method on some repository class that returns a `CompletableFuture`. The code that completes these futures uses a third party library which blocks. I intend to have a separate bounded `Executor` which this repository class will use to make these blocking calls.

Here is an example:

```
public class PersonRepository {
    private Executor executor = ...
    public CompletableFuture<Void> create(Person person) {...}
    public CompletableFuture<Boolean> delete(Person person) {...}
}
```

The rest of my application will compose these futures and do some other things with the results. When these other functions that are supplied to `thenAccept`, `thenCompose`, `whenComplete`, etc, I don't want them to run on the `Executor` for the repository.

Another example:

```
public CompletableFuture<?> replacePerson(Person person) {
    final PersonRepository repo = getPersonRepository();
    return repo.delete(person)
        .thenAccept(existed -> {
            if (existed) System.out.println("Person deleted"));
            else System.out.println("Person did not exist"));
        })
        .thenCompose(unused -> {
            System.out.println("Creating person");
            return repo.create(person);
        })
        .whenComplete((unused, ex) -> {
            if (ex != null) System.out.println("Creating person");
            repo.close();
        });
}
```

The JavaDoc states:

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method.

**Side question:** Why is there an *or* here? In what case is there another caller of a completion method that does not complete the current future?

**Main question:** If I want all the `println` to be executed by a different `Executor` than the one used by the repository, which methods do I need to make async and provide the executor manually?

Obviously the `thenAccept` needs to be changed to `thenAcceptAsync` but I'm not sure about that point onwards.

**Alternative question:** Which thread completes the returned future from `thenCompose`?

My guess is that it will be whatever thread completes the future returned from the function argument. In other words I would need to also change `whenComplete` to `whenCompleteAsync`.

Perhaps I am over complicating things but this feels like it could get quite tricky. I need to pay a lot of attention to where all these futures come from. Also from a design point of view, if I return a future, how do I prevent callers from using my executor? It feels like it breaks encapsulation. I know that all the transformation functions in Scala take an implicit `ExecutionContext` which seems to solve all these problems.

Comment: Read that article - http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/11/which-thread-executes.html. It helps to shade a light on threads work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Side Question: If you assigned the intermediate `CompletionStage` to a variable and call a method on it, it would get executed on the same thread.

Main Question: Only the first one, so change `thenAccept` to `thenAcceptAsync` -- all the following ones will execute their steps on the thread that is used for the accept.

Alternative Question: the thread that completed the future from `thenCompose` is the same one as was used for the compose.

You should think of the CompletionStages as steps, that are executed in rapid succession on the same thread (by just applying the functions in order), unless you specifically want the step to be executed on a different thread, using async.  All next steps are done on that new thread then.

In your current setup the steps would be executed like this:

```
Thread-1: delete, accept, compose, complete
```

With the first accept async, it becomes:

```
Thread-1: delete
Thread-2: accept, compose, complete
```

As for your last question, about the same thread being used by your callers if they add additional steps -- I don't think there is much you can do about aside from not returning a `CompletableFuture`, but a normal `Future`.

Comment: Your answer to the side question doesn't make sense to me. Assignment shouldn't make any difference. Your answers also contradict what @joe-c said and the article in the comment above. If I have understood what they have said then nothing will necessarily execute on the same thread (without async) unless they are either all complete or all incomplete during the composition. If at some point during the composition the intermediate future is completed then the next composition will run in the current thread.

Comment: Yeah, I worded that unclear, it's more that if you kept a stage around long enough, and it is completed already, then doing more compositions on it would be on the caller thread.  So that "or" in the docs basically is for the case where stages have completed already.

Comment: Perhaps a little confusing given the other answers but this is the correct answer for the main question. Once an executor is explicitly passed to an async combinator then both the function argument and the resulting future is executed by that executor.

Answer (score 5):

Just from my empirical observations while playing around with it, the thread that executes these non-async methods will depend on which happens first, `thenCompose` itself or the task behind the `Future`.

If `thenCompose` completes first (which, in your case, is almost certain), then the method will run on the same thread that is executing the `Future` task.

If the task behind your `Future` completes first, then the method will run immediately on the calling thread (i.e. no executor at all).

Comment: Ah yes of course. I hadn't considered that the other future could actually complete before the current thread has finished composing them (although as you pointed out this is quite unlikely in my case). I still wonder about the inner future though, applying the same logic to that it seems like the resulting one may still be completed by the executor for that. I might have to experiment a little more on that one