# CompletableFuture.thenAccept can indeed block

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

Unlike stated in some blogs(e.g. [I can't emphasize this enough: thenAccept()/thenRun() methods do not block](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html)) `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` can indeed block. Consider the following code, uncommenting the `pause` method call will cause `thenAccept` to block:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    log.trace("return 42");
    return "42";
});

//pause(1000); //uncommenting this will cause blocking of thenAccept

future.thenAccept((dbl -> {
    log.trace("blocking");
    pause(500);
    log.debug("Result: " + dbl);
}));

log.trace("end");
pause(1000);
```

Can we be sure that the following will not block? It's my understanding that if the `supplyAsync` runs immediately then the `thenAccept` could block, no?

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    return "42";
}).thenAccept((dbl -> {
    pause(500);
    log.debug("Result: " + dbl);
}));
```

Comment: Did this not print following lines? 
end 
blocking 
Result: 42

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are right, `thenAccept()` will block if the future is already completed. Also note that when it is not the case, it will cause the thread that completes it to block at the time of completion.

This is why you have [`thenAcceptAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAcceptAsync-java.util.function.Consumer-), which will run your `Consumer` in a non-blocking way:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    return "42";
}).thenAcceptAsync((dbl -> {
    pause(500);
    log.debug("Result: " + dbl);
}));
```

See also [Which executor is used when composing Java CompletableFutures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42705950/525036)